# column is amguously defined in column

Tags: oracle11g

my tables

```
DESC emp

Name                           Null     Type
------------------------------ -------- --------------------------
EMP_NO                                  NUMBER
EMP_NAME                                VARCHAR2(10)
ADDRESS                                 VARCHAR2(15)
PH_NO                                   NUMBER(10)
DEPT_NO                                 NUMBER
```

result:

```
1   ram ctr 8892939927  100
2   mohan   ptr 7569936347  101
3   mallu   ppt 9553438342  102
4   scoot   dmc 9874563210  103
5   jim plr 9236548875  104
6   ravi    tpt 8562398756  105
7   manju   hyd 7562398742  106
8   manoj   hyd 869523654   107
9   sarath  ctr 9632158769  108
10  hemanth mpk 9632147852  109


desc salary

Name                           Null     Type
------------------------------ -------- --------------------------
EMP_NO                                  NUMBER
SALARY                                  NUMBER(10)
PERIOD                                  VARCHAR2(10)
START_DATE                              DATE
END_DATE                                DATE
```

result:

```
1   12580   15months    12-DEC-07   10-DEC-10
2   15500   19months    10-JAN-07   10-DEC-11
3   7777    18months    11-JUL-07   21-APR-11
4   9999    11months    07-JUL-07   31-JAN-11
5   8500    9months         12-MAR-07   27-MAR-11
6   10000   20months    17-SEP-07   01-AUG-11
7   25000   7months         17-NOV-07   26-JUL-11
8   100000  6months         05-MAY-07   21-JUN-11
9   35000   16months    28-FEB-08   21-JUN-11
10  5000    16months    02-DEC-08   19-AUG-11
```

joinning query :

```
select emp_no,
       emp_name,
       dpt_no,
       salary 
from emp 
   join salary on emp.dpt_no=salary.dpt_no
```

but am getting error is"column is amguously defined". How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Prefix each column with its table name in the select list.

Comment: i didn't get u.plese give example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the columns in the select list (the way it's done in the `JOIN` condition). Otherwise Oracle wouldn't know from which table the column `dept_no` should be taken.

```
select emp.emp_no,
       emp.emp_name,
       emp.dpt_no,  
       salary.salary 
from emp 
   join salary on emp.dpt_no=salary.dpt_no;
```

It's good coding style to *always* qualify the columns - at least in a query involving more than one table - even if they are not ambigous.

If you don't want to type the full table name, you can use a (maningful) alias:

```
select emp.emp_no,
       emp.emp_name,
       emp.dpt_no,  
       sal.salary, 
       sal.period
from emp 
   join salary sal 
     on emp.dpt_no = sal.dpt_no;
```

Comment: i got my desire out put

Answer (score 0):

If the columnname is the same in tables (salary and emp) and youre joining the tables, you have to specify form wich table you want to selecte the column (salary or from emp)

in youre case the solution is to use **salary.dpt_no** instead of **dpt_no**

> select emp_no,emp_name, salary.dpt_no,salary from emp join salary on emp.dpt_no=salary.dpt_no